# How do I stop DHCP to request address for a static interface?

Tags: networking, raspberrypi, dhcp, 21.10, static-ip

I have a Raspberry PI 4 running Ubuntu 21.10 with a static ip-address on eth0. Despite that, I keep getting a secondary 'dynamic' DHCP address on on it.

netplan

```
  network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.10/23
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
          search: [lan]
          addresses: [192.168.0.12]
```

ip addr show

```
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:da:df:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.10/23 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.225/23 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 68727sec preferred_lft 68727sec
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:feda:df55/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Even if I delete that interface, it keeps coming back after a few minutes. I have another PI with the "same" configuration and it doesn't have this problem.
I also have the **/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg** per instructions.

Comment: One way is to add your IP address to your DHCP server as a reserved IP so only your Raspberry Pi gets that address.

Comment: Is the address x.10 outside the DHCP pool in the router? Is the result chnged with xxx/24 instead of xxx/23?

Comment: Yes, the DHCP pool is .201 - .251. I run the /23 so I can handle devices with 192.168.1.xxx. I'll test with /24...

Comment: No, changing to /24 didn't help. It's still requesting the .225 address (but now with 0.225 instead of 1.225).

Comment: You will need to set it back to /23 if you want the 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.1.254 to be all in the same network.  I did notice that you are missing the `dhcp4: no` and `dhcp6: no` right below your `eth0:` above `addresses:` in your .yaml file.

Comment: Are there actually two networks here? 0 and 1? Please explain.

Comment: No, there's only the 0 network but sometimes a need to hook up a device that defaults to 192.168.1.xxx, hence the /23. But I really only need that on 1 machine so all the others are going to stay /24 for now on. I just added the dhcp?: no, lets see if that helps...

Comment: no, dhcp4: no didn't help either :-(